# Wordpress 3 Level horizontal navigation - need jquery / javascript help for alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation

I have been trying to achieve a 3 level horizontal navigation but I am stuck on the last one. I have to use position absolute on the last level because making it relative will bound the menu item width to the width of the parent which is a menu item in the second level.

I am not very familiar with javascript/jquery but I want to make sure the child element will always stay under the parent.

http://generatedesignstaging.com/safari/safaris/value-safaris/the-beast-retreat/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with and it works pretty nicely.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
    var submenu = jQuery('#top-menu').position().top+jQuery('#top-menu').outerHeight(true);
      jQuery('.sub-menu').css('top',submenu);

/** 3rd level navigation top position **/ 
var height_sm = jQuery('#top-menu').find('.sub-menu').outerHeight();
jQuery('.menu-item .menu-item > .sub-menu').css('top', height_sm);   

/** Maximum width of the page **/  
var container = $('#page-container').width(); 

/** Compute horizontal position of the 3rd menu **/ 
$('#top-menu').find('.sub-menu .menu-item-has-children').each(function() { 
    var item = $(this).children('.sub-menu').width(); 
    var position = $(this).position();
    var total = item + position.left; 
    if (total > container){
        var ofset = total-container; 
        var calc = position.left - ofset;  

        $(this).children('.sub-menu').css('left',calc);
    }
    else{
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').css('left',position.left);
}
}); 
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```